# Collect values on grouped field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

With given data

```
{
    "type": "INGESTION",
    "message": "Lorem"
}

{
    "type": "INGESTION",
    "message": "Ipsum"
}

{
    "type": "DISCHARGE",
    "message": "dolor"
}

{
    "type": "DISCHARGE",
    "message": "sit"
}
```

I want to group by `type` and collecting all possible values of `message` into one single field.

The expected output should be something along the lines of

```
[{
    "type": "INGESTION",
    "messages": ["Lorem", "Ipsum"]
},
{
    "type": "DISCHARGE",
    "messages": ["dolor", "sit"]
}]
```

I have tried several aggregation queries, none of which have led to a result that I could be satisfied with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-title-by-author) which describes your same situation.

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$type",
            "messages": { $push: "$message" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Alternatively use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` if you do want unique entries in that array